# Quake/Doom like command prompt for Windows

Tags: command-line, powershell

I'm after a Doom-like command prompt, whereby I can could press a keyboard shortcut like CTRL Tab and the command prompt will scroll down from the top like Doom, Quake, etc.

Also if it works with Powershell that would be even better.

Comment: When you say, "and the command prompt will scroll down from the top," do you mean that you want a DOS window to be launched?

Comment: ...exactly, a DOS window will appear.  I was thinking it would be great to have it, just scroll into view when called upon, and disappear otherwise.

Comment: +1, there's something like this for Terminal on OS X but I haven't seen it for Windows.

Comment: Oh, a command prompt for Windows like the old-style FPS console controls would be AWESOME.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See http://poshconsole.codeplex.com - Joel has implemented a "quake mode" that works exactly like you say.

Answer (score 10):

poshconsole doesn't work too good, and his development isn't very active.
i recomend you to install console2 http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/ and autohotkey, http://www.autohotkey.com/, and use this script:

```
#|::

DetectHiddenWindows, on
IfWinExist ahk_class Console_2_Main
{
IfWinActive ahk_class Console_2_Main
  {

        WinHide ahk_class Console_2_Main
        if(temptitle="") 
            WinActivate ahk_class Shell_TrayWnd
        else
            WinActivate %temptitle%
    }
else
  {
    WinGetActiveTitle, temptitle
    WinShow ahk_class Console_2_Main
    WinActivate ahk_class Console_2_Main
  }
}
else{
WinGetActiveTitle, temptitle
Run Console.exe
}
DetectHiddenWindows, off
return
```

**Result**

I just press win+| and i have mi transparent console running powershell. If i press again it disappear, :)

Comment: Wish they'd include this feature in console2

Answer (score 6):

Quake/tilde mode was implemented in ConEmu [build 120612](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/wiki/Whats_New?wl=en#Build_120612). I'm the author of this [console emulator](http://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/).

You can choose almost any hotkey in Settings/Keys (which can be registered through [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Set pad (in pixels) around console area.

It is possible to resize window with mouse, while frame is completely hidden (just hold mouse cursor over place where frame must be, and frame will appears). Or from keyboard (look an Settings/Keys).

Sample settings provided in distrib - "ConEmu\ConEmu_Tilde.xml", just rename this file to "ConEmu.xml".